# call two functions in onClick with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Someone would know how can I call two functions in `onClick` with ReactJs ?
I have a `Row` which redirect to another component and in this `Row` I have a `Button` for delete this `Row` by his `index`.I would like to delete the `Row` and prevent the redirection in the same `onClick`.

I have two functions, both work but not together..

The first one:

`onClick={() => deleteFournisseur(idx)}`

And the second one:

`onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}`

Comment: How about `(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); deleteFournisseur(idx) }`?

Comment: Why not just do `{(e) => deleteFournisseur(idx, e)` and do `e.stopPropagation()` inside that function?

Comment: @AtinSingh No. That is a bad suggestion. `delete` function should care for deletion only. You should not drill event to inner function unless required. You should have specific functions that addresses single task

Comment: @Rajesh Hmm.. i see you got a point.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call it like this.

```
onClick={e => {
   deleteFournisseur(idx);
   e.stopPropagation();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Inline

{ func1(); func2();}}>Test Link

2) With Inline classes

class Test extends React.Component {
   onClick(event) {

```
 func1();
 func2();
```

}
   render() {
     return (
        Test Link
    );
   }
}